# AWS x-ray max data retention and retrival

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

AWS documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/faqs/) says that they retain traces for 30 days and enable users to query traces upto last 30 days. However, when I look at the console, I see max 6 hours and dont see an option to go back in days. Is it available via the console?

PS: I did find AWS CLI supporting current time - 6 months query..wondering if AWS console supports the same

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the same screenshot you can see two time selections - custom and relative. You can select custom tab within that selector and then a calendar will pop up to select a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not select a range which is more than 6 hours. You should find the exact 6 hour range you are interested in (for example, if it is for a Lambda function you can check the Invocations metric in the Monitoring tab) and then specify a custom range in the Traces console using the Absolute tab where you can specify Start time and End time. If you specify a range longer than 6 hours you will not be able to apply this range. Also note that if this is for a Lambda function, the time in the Invocation metric is in UTC. When you select the 6 hour range make sure that you select the UTC option and not the Local option, otherwise you may not be able to see your traces.